# Button drawable icon not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to display a normal icon on before the text on the button.
I know how it should work and I don't know why it doesn't.

Things I have already tried:

- most basic and isolated button
- multiple or no styles
- multiple icons
- all stack overflow answers I could find didn't work for me

Here is the code I use:

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
    android:text="Button with Left Icon" />
```

Any tips on what I could try or how I could make a button with icon differently?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try like this

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_black_24dp"

    />
```

Comment: When I changed <Button to <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton it worked! Thanks!